# C++ Hangman Game

Tags: c++, loops

I am a beginner to programming and am practicing by making a hangman game. The user must input yes to begin the game sequence, type no to close the program, or any other input results in an error message. If three consecutive error messages occur, the program should close. When testing the program, I noticed that the program only catches the consecutive errors if all three are typed before saying yes to begin the game. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyFuncts.h"
#include "randword.h"
using namespace std;

int incorrectCount = 0;
int consecutiveErrors = 0;
void drawHangman(int incorrectCount);

int main()
{
getWords("hangman.dat");

string reply;
string wordToGuess;
char guessLetter;
do
{
    location2: if (consecutiveErrors == 3)
    break;
    cout << "\nDo you want to play hangman? (y or n): ";
    cin >> reply;
    promptYN(reply);
    if (promptYN(reply) == PLAY)
    {
        cout << "Let's PLAY\n\n";
        wordToGuess = strToUpper(getNextWord());
        if (wordToGuess == "")
            break;
        cout << "Word to Guess: " << wordToGuess << endl << endl;
        while (incorrectCount < 6 && wordToGuess != "")
        {
            drawHangman(incorrectCount);
            cout << "Enter a letter to guess: ";
            cin >> guessLetter;
            guessLetter = toupper(guessLetter);
            cout << "You entered: " << guessLetter << endl << endl;
            if (wordToGuess.find(guessLetter) != string::npos)
                cout << guessLetter << " is in the word to guess.\n\n";
            else
            {
                cout << guessLetter << " is NOT in the word to guess.\n\n";
                incorrectCount++;
            }
                if (incorrectCount == 6)
                {
                    cout << " -------|\n"
                        " |      |\n"
                        " O      |\n"
                        "-|-     |\n"
                        "/ \\     |\n"
                        "        |\n"
                        "      -----\n\n";
                    cout << "Sorry you lose - the word was: " << wordToGuess << endl << endl;
                    incorrectCount = 0;
                    cout << "\nDo you want to play hangman? (y or n): ";
                    cin >> reply;
                    promptYN(reply);
                    if (promptYN(reply) == PLAY)
                    {
                        consecutiveErrors = 0;
                        cout << "Let's PLAY\n\n";
                        wordToGuess = strToUpper(getNextWord());
                        if (wordToGuess == "")
                            break;
                        cout << "Word to Guess: " << wordToGuess << endl << endl;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (promptYN(reply) == STOP)
                        goto location3;
                    else
                        goto location4;
                }
            }
        }
    else if (promptYN(reply) == STOP)
    {
        location3: cout << "Goodbye";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        location4: consecutiveErrors++;
        cout << "Error - please enter (y or n)\n";
        goto location2;
        }
} while (wordToGuess != "" && consecutiveErrors < 3);
}

void drawHangman(int incorrectCount)
{
    if (incorrectCount == 0)
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 1)
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            " O      |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 2)
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            " O      |\n"
            " |      |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 3)
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            " O      |\n"
            "-|      |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 4)
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            " O      |\n"
            "-|-     |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
else if (incorrectCount == 5)
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            " O      |\n"
            "-|-     |\n"
            "/       |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
else
    cout << " -------|\n"
            " |      |\n"
            " O      |\n"
            "-|-     |\n"
            "/ \\     |\n"
            "        |\n"
            "      -----\n\n";
}
```

Comment: did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: And your question is?  Also I strongly suggest you get out of the habit of using `goto`.  You can use loops and functions to replace `goto` and the [spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) it produces.

Comment: I predict that few will want to look at the code that is spaghetti.  That's the risk you take when you riddle your code with `goto` statements -- persons who would try to help are not going to sit there and try to untangle `goto` code.

Comment: I would expect that even if this works any good professor will take points off for the use of gotos.

Comment: When you write code, it behooves you to develop new functionality in isolation as much as possible. Get this "three chances" thing working *before* you attach it to the code for playing a game.

Comment: Here come the cargo cult `goto`-haters lol

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are valid reasons to use `goto`. This code does not represent any of them, and instead represents compensation for poor program design.

Comment: @Xirema: Indeed. You would not count as a cargo cult `goto`-hater. But that's not what the others said.

Comment: Alright, I will work on replacing the gotos then. Sorry, in my long-winded explanation I didn't exactly mention the specific problem I was having. In short, I want the program to terminate whenever three consecutive promptYN "errors" occur, but this only works if I don't input any promptYN "yes" inputs between the "errors". I am unsure of how to implement this. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: When you're goto targets are in the middle of `else` blocks, then there is something almost sadistic about the code.

Comment: ***This code does not represent any of them, and instead represents compensation for poor program design*** That is why I mentioned the gotos.

Comment: What does `promptYN(reply)` do? Can't you store the returning value in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

You have counters (like `incorrectCount` and `consecutiveErrors`) that should be reset when appropriate; for example, at the start of a new game.